# dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: has a couple second delay

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uikit

dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: is working fine in my application, except for the delay between the dismissal.

```
[api loginWithUsername:[dict objectForKey:@"username"] andPassword:[dict objectForKey:@"password"] andSuccessBlock:^(id json) {
    NSLog(@"DONE... %@", [json objectForKey:@"status"]);
    NSString *status = [json objectForKey:@"status"];
    if([status isEqualToString:@"ok"]){
        app.user = [json objectForKey:@"data"];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"could not log you in" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}];
```

In my console I can see echo'ed "DONE... ok", meaning the callback block was executed, however about 3-4 seconds later the modal view is finally dismissed.

What could be causing this delay?

Comment: Use Instrument's Time profiler to see what takes the most time

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you don't guarantee your UI code is running on Main Thread it might run on some other and in that case, you will experience a few seconds delay!

You can add this to make sure that dismissal is ran on main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Generally, this is not an issue as most of your code will already be running on main thread, since we mostly add code that runs from UIKit methods, like viewDidLoad and such. Those methods are guaranteed to be ran on the main thread.

The issue arises when you end up running code on another thread. One case where that can happen is for example on a completion block invocation of a networking library, where the request is done on background.

Comment: this was exactly the problem.

Comment: May I know why do I need this?
I have a simple PresentedViewcontroller. At some point I execute
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            
            [self.delegate funcDidSelected];
            
        }];

and when I dismiss the presentedViewController it takes 5 seconds to execute it. My presentingViewController does not do complex thing instead of having a simple UITableView.

Comment: @Felix because dismissing and presenting view controllers is a UI action. All UI actions must be ran on the main thread of the app. The behavior of you running such actions on any other thread, are usually a big delay, or even them having no effect. Most of your code already runs on main thread so you usually don't need to worry about this, but on some cases you do.

Comment: @manecosta Yes there's a delegated function in my presentingViewController and when its being called from presentedViewController, and it will perform push viewcontroller after dismiss the presentedViewController. As what you said above I guess it might already effect the code execution in main thread. Thank you very much. I learned something new and understand better on the main-thread execution.

Comment: manecosta solution solved my problem. For some reason there were a noticeable lag (up to 2,3 seconds) for my modal view controller to dismiss. I used the following syntax in Swift 2.1.1 which solves the lag problem. Note: picker is my view controller object that is passed to its delegate. One of the delegate's tasks is to close the picker view controller: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

Answer (score 3):

check '`viewWillAppear`' of the ParentViewController and '`viewWillDisappear`' of the currentViewcontroller.
Make sure this two functions does not have any heavy calculations and memory allocations within.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

> ```
> NSString *status = [json objectForKey:@"status"];
> NSLog(@"DONE... %@", status);
> ```

and then try

> if([status isEqualToString:@"ok"]){
>
> ```
>     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
>     app.user = [json objectForKey:@"data"];
> }else{
> ```

As I don't know how big your JSON object is it could be taking a moment to respond and as you're calling it again after the log statement and the doing something else before saying dismiss it could be that.